# How can i delete image file in external storage after email sent?

Tags: android

i am storing image in External storage using MediaStore,and send email with attach that image,image saved and sent email with attachment is working fine,i want to delete that image in external storage after mail sent.anybody knows,please give sample code for me..

Thanks All,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a one-time alarm with `AlarmManager` to delete your image after a reasonable period of time (e.g., an hour).

Comment: @I can't understand your answer..Thanks

Comment: @hi,how can use AlarmManager  in android,please give sample code for me

Comment: Why not delete it on (responseCode == 200) instead why wait for 1 hour?

Comment: @codingcrow: My assumption is that the OP is sending the email via `ACTION_SEND` and therefore there is no response code.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential answer would be to create a new thread when your app resumes, immediately mark the current time, sleep the thread for however long you feel is reasonable for the file to be sent, and when the thread resumes, only delete files created before the previously marked time.  This will give you the ability to only delete what was in the storage location at the time your app was resumed, but also give time to gmail to get the email out.  Code snippet: (I'm using C#/Xamarin, but you should get the idea)

```
    public static void ClearTempFiles()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {

            try
            {
                DateTime threadStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(DeletionDelayMinutes));
                DirectoryInfo tempFileDir = new DirectoryInfo(TempFilePath);
                FileInfo[] tempFiles = tempFileDir.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo tempFile in tempFiles)
                {
                    if (tempFile.CreationTimeUtc < threadStartTime)
                    {
                        File.Delete(tempFile.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        });
    }
```