# How can i delete image file in SD cardafter email sent?

Tags: android

I want to delete image file in SD card after sending email...anybody knows,please give sample code for me...

Thanks All

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i delete image file in external storage after email sent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754040/how-can-i-delete-image-file-in-external-storage-after-email-sent)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the file?  What sort of file?  What have you tried?  What didn't work?

Have you checked out the [Android Data Storage Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)?  It's all in there.

```
deleteFile()
```

Or perhaps

```
context.getFileStringPath("your_filename.txt").delete();
```

Comment: @ i am developing application for image,which image user click and then user like send email,that image attach and send email,it work fine,i want to delete that image in sdcard after sent email?

Comment: Like I said: use the delete functions detailed in the Android docs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if you want to wait for the e-mail to be sent. The e-mail activity is not giving you back any clue on when the e-mail is sent or even if the e-mail was sent